# Se va el audio despues de varios clicks en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo un botón donde el usuario puede dar muchos clicks seguidos para reproducir un sonido muy corto, el problema es que despues de demasiados clicks seguidos, el audio ya no suena y despues de un ratito vuelve, lo que quiero es que el audio no se vaya aunque sean muchos clicks.
Se que si se puede pero supongo que necesito alguna libreria o algo.

```
  async playAudio() {
    const setAudio = new Audio("./../../assets/sounds/slap.mp3");
    setAudio.load();
    await setAudio.play();
  }
```

Comment: Te puedo recomendar usar [howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler), su  documentacion e implementacion es bastante sencilla.

Comment: ya quedó, muchas gracias :l